Why does Column from another site collection shows under managed property?
I'm site collection administrator of 2 site collections.
In site collection 1, under site settings when I go to search schema -> managed property, I can see column names from the other site collection as well.
Is this expected behaviour? Why does search schema managed property of one site collection show managed property and crawled property from the other site collection?

Yes, this is expected behavior. As a site collection administrator, you can see all managed properties and crawled properties from all site collections within the same tenant. This is because the search schema is managed at the tenant level, and not at the site collection level. Therefore, any changes made to the search schema at the tenant level will affect all site collections within the same tenant.
References:
Manage the search schema in SharePoint
Overview of crawled and managed properties in SharePoint Online

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Change made at sitecollection search schema will effect tenant level and vice versa?

The links you provided suggest You can change the search schema for the whole tenant or for a specific site collection only. The search schema for the site collection is based on the search schema for the tenant, so typically, you would make changes on the tenant level first, and then on the site collection level. Any changes you make on a site collection, only apply to that site collection.
